# Starting Codeready Container with libvirt cause "format of backing image was not specified in the image metadata"

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, virtualization, libvirt, redhat-containers

I'm trying to use CRC for testing Openshift 4 on my laptop (Ubuntu 20). CRC version 1.17 doesn't support Virtualbox virtualizazion so following the setup instructions

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_codeready_containers/1.17/html/getting_started_guide/installation_gsg

i'm using libvirt, but when i start the cluster with `crc start` it launch following error

```
INFO Checking if oc binary is cached              
INFO Checking if podman remote binary is cached   
INFO Checking if goodhosts binary is cached       
INFO Checking minimum RAM requirements            
INFO Checking if running as non-root              
INFO Checking if Virtualization is enabled        
INFO Checking if KVM is enabled                   
INFO Checking if libvirt is installed             
INFO Checking if user is part of libvirt group    
INFO Checking if libvirt daemon is running        
INFO Checking if a supported libvirt version is installed 
INFO Checking if crc-driver-libvirt is installed  
INFO Checking if libvirt 'crc' network is available 
INFO Checking if libvirt 'crc' network is active  
INFO Checking if NetworkManager is installed      
INFO Checking if NetworkManager service is running 
INFO Checking if /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/crc-nm-dnsmasq.conf exists 
INFO Checking if /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/crc.conf exists 
INFO Starting CodeReady Containers VM for OpenShift 4.5.14... 
ERRO Error starting stopped VM: virError(Code=55, Domain=18, Message='Requested operation is not valid: format of backing image '/home/claudiomerli/.crc/cache/crc_libvirt_4.5.14/crc.qcow2' of image '/home/claudiomerli/.crc/machines/crc/crc.qcow2' was not specified in the image metadata (See https://libvirt.org/kbase/backing_chains.html for troubleshooting)') 
Error starting stopped VM: virError(Code=55, Domain=18, Message='Requested operation is not valid: format of backing image '/home/claudiomerli/.crc/cache/crc_libvirt_4.5.14/crc.qcow2' of image '/home/claudiomerli/.crc/machines/crc/crc.qcow2' was not specified in the image metadata (See https://libvirt.org/kbase/backing_chains.html for troubleshooting)')
```

I have not experiences with libvirt so i'm stuck on that and online i'm not finding anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue with the crc_libvirt_4.5.14 image. The easiest way to fix it is to do a

```
qemu-img rebase -f qcow2 -F qcow2 -b /home/${USER}/.crc/cache/crc_libvirt_4.5.14/crc.qcow2 /home/${USER}/.crc/machines/crc/crc.qcow2
```

Now, if you try to do a `crc start`, you going to face a "Permission denied" error, which is related to Apparmor, unless you whitelisted your home directory. If you don't want to hack around with Apparmor settings, the `/var/lib/libvirt/images` supposed to be whitelisted. Move the image to there:

```
sudo mv /home/${USER}/.crc/machines/crc/crc.qcow2 /var/lib/libvirt/images
```

then edit the virtual machine settings pointing to the new image location: `virsh edit crc` , then replace the  `<source file='/home/yourusername/.crc/machines/crc/crc.qcow2'/>` to `<source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/crc.qcow2'/>`.

Then do the `crc start` and... that's it.

The relevant Github issues to follow:

- https://github.com/code-ready/crc/issues/1596
- https://github.com/code-ready/crc/issues/1578

Comment: Thanks man!! After rebasing the image i faced the permission denied error. I simply added problematic path inside /etc/apparmor.d/libvirt/TEMPLATE.qemu and all worked fine.